# "ps aux" works but "ps -aux" doesn't

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, command

This might seem like a silly question but I haven't been able to find a clear answer.

[This website](http://www.linfo.org/ps.html) states that the dash is optional in

```
ps aux
```

However, `ps aux` works but `ps -aux` brings up the error `no user named 'x'`.  Any ideas what the issue may be here?  Running Mac 10.8.2.  Thanks

Comment: This question should be reopened; checking for process existence is definitely a 'programming tool'.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
man ps
```

will give you this:

> ```
>  The biggest change is in the interpretation of the -u option, which now
>  displays processes belonging to the specified username(s).  Thus, "ps
>  -aux" will fail (unless you want to know about user "x").  As a conve-
>  nience, however, "ps aux" still works as it did in Tiger.
> ```

Comment: bah thanks, i'm still a newbie when it comes to UNIX commands

Answer (score 12):

Back in the day (from the late 1970s), there were basically two varieties of UNIX, the AT&T version from Bell Labs and the BSD version from UC Berkeley.  The options to ps were different in the two versions.  OS X now mostly conforms to the modern UNIX standard which follows the AT&T options to ps.  But since the BSD ps didn't require a leading '-' option and so many people were used to typing 'ps aux', Apple has decided to leave that sequence with its original BSD interpretation.